# Changing Activities at Android Studio without using a button

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I've been developing an application at Android Studio as a college project for a while but I got stuck.

I wanted to know if there is anyway to change activities by not using a button but using a timer. Like: "wait ten seconds then change to that activity".

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use do it this way

```
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {

         Intent intent = new Intent(this, Another.class);
         startActivity(intent);
            }

         }, 1000);`
```

or

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
 public void run() {
     // do something
     Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityName.this, Another.class);
     // If you just use this that is not a valid context. Use ActivityName.this
     startActivity(intent);
   }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried both but my app start with an error? I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: link your error

Comment: I found the error. It was very simple. Thank you. You helped me a lot.